# Simple Selenium RegEx Java

Tags: java, regex, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not familiar with how to use Reg Ex within Selenium, so was hoping I could get some assistance with this.  Currently, when it is run, it doesn't locate any elements which is not that surprising.

```
List<WebElement> elements = SeleniumCommands.myDriver.findElements(By.id("assessment-answer-{[0-9]+}-1"));
```

The ids of what I'm trying to grab look like

```
<input id="assessment-answer-5713185-1" ...>
```

Here is a larger HTML parse of the site for selection-writing purposes.

```
<div id="assessment-page-1">
  <ul id="question-row-5713185" class="plus-card card-white question-row">
    <li id="question-collapsible-5713185" class="question-collapsible">
    <li id="answers-container-5713185" class="answers-container">
      <div class=" assessment-two-answers">
      <input id="assessment-answer-5713185-1" type="radio" value="1" name="assessment-answer-5713185"/>
      <label class="assessment-answer-right answer-1" for="assessment-answer-5713185-1">Agree</label>
      <input id="assessment-answer-5713185-2" type="radio" value="2" name="assessment-answer-5713185"/>
      <label class="assessment-answer-left answer-2" for="assessment-answer-5713185-2">Disagree</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="question-row-16432246" class="plus-card card-white question-row">
    <li id="question-collapsible-16432246" class="question-collapsible">
    <li id="answers-container-16432246" class="answers-container">
  </ul>
  <ul id="question-row-62590768" class="plus-card card-white question-row">
  <ul id="question-row-16162378" class="plus-card card-white question-row">
  <ul id="question-row-34160582" class="plus-card card-white question-row">

...
</div>
```

I am not very experienced with Reg Ex which I know is likely the cause of my problem, so I apologize for the simple question, but would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *starts-with* and *ends-with* locator/notation:

```
List<WebElement> elements = SeleniumCommands.myDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^=assessment-answer-][id$=\"-1\"]"));
```

You may also need to wait for the element to become visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumCommands.myDriver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[id^=assessment-answer-][id$=\"-1\"]")));

List<WebElement> elements = SeleniumCommands.myDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^=assessment-answer-][id$=\"-1\"]"));
```

Comment: This would be a great answer, but I do need it to also end with `"-1"`.  It can't just start with `"assessment-answer-"`

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason this is not working.  I will provide more HTML in the original; stay tuned.

Comment: @lmcphers before you do that, could  you please try with double quotes - updated the selector.

Comment: Original post updated. Let me know if that helps or if you need something else.

Comment: @lmcphers okay, good, let's first start with a sanity check: `List<WebElement> elements = SeleniumCommands.myDriver.findElements(By.id("assessment-answer-5713185-1"));` - does it locate the element? Also, what about this: `List<WebElement> elements = SeleniumCommands.myDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^=assessment-answer-]"));`

Comment: For some reason the first did not work.  When I try to do the second one, I get a java illegal character error.

`Error:(515, 117) java: illegal character: '\u200c'
Error:(515, 118) java: illegal character: '\u200b'
Error:(515, 119) java: illegal start of expression
Error:(515, 120) java: ';' expected`

Answer (score 1):

You may also construct xpath with the help of ID (or part of id) to find the webelement. In that case, your code should look like below:

`List<WebElement> elements = SeleniumCommands.myDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'assessment-answer-')]"));`

To explain the xpath constructed:

`//` - to find the element at any hierarchy in the dom

`*` - To identify the tag name. If we know the tag name, we can pass the same. If unsure of the tag-name, pass it as `*`

`[contains(XX,XX)]` - Adding a filter to the xpath

`@id` - Filter criteria

`assessment-answer-` - This is the partial id (which is always constant)

Give a try.

Good luck.

Comment: Really great explanation, thank you for this write-up.  I appreciate and will reference this as I continue working with Selenium.

Comment: @lmcphers Xpath is an alternative option. The problem though is that you cannot use `ends-with()` to check the end of the id here. `ends-with` is a part of XPath 2.0 only.